# iPhone - area available inside a UITabbarController

Tags: iphone

I have a viewController that is being loaded as a tab on a UITabBarController.

How do I know, inside the viewController class, how much area I have available to show this viewController. I ask this because this VC is also shown inside a popover on iPad, using a specific size. On iPhone, I like it to fill the whole area available for a tab content, that is the screen size less that tab size in the bottom.

How do I get the value of this area inside the VC when it is inside a UITabBarController?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no direct method for that then since `UITabBarController` is a subclass of `UIViewController` you can access its `view` size and get the difference of its `tabBar` frame size:

```
CGSize viewSize =  self.tabBarController.view.frame.size;
CGSize tabBarSize = self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size;
CGSize vcSize = CGSizeMake(viewSize.width, viewSize.height - tabBarSize.height);
```

Comment: thanks. It says tabBarController undeclared... how can I declare a tabBarController in a viewController that can be used on a popover or in a tabbarcontroller?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you were inside a UIViewController, its fixed now ;)